# Form with checkbox that is required to continue (if not displays an error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, required

Alright so basically I have a form that i added a checkbox to (agree to terms of service check box) anyways i need to make it so that it needs to be checked to continue with the donation process... I only have the HTML code i have no idea how to make this work.. Also if not checked i want a javascript alert to pop up displaying the error "You must agree to the terms of service".

Heres my HTML code

```
<form method="POST">
<!-- Add ranks with a new value on the next line! -->
<select name="rank">
<option value="1">Donator ($1.20)</option>
<option value="2">Moderator ($5.00)</option>
<option value="3">Administrator ($13.37)</option>
<option value="4">Super-Administrator ($33.00)</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="required">I agree to the <a href="/donate/tos/"> terms of service</a>.<br /><br />
<input type="submit" role="button" type="submit" value="Donate" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

I'm pretty sure this is done with javascript except i have very very little experience with javascript & wouldn't know how to accomplish this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
put this code in your <head> :-
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function IsTermChecked() {
        if (!$("input:checkbox").is(":checked")) {
            alert("You must agree to the terms of service.");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

</script>
</head>
Also call the function IsTermChecked() on submit click :-

<input type="submit" role="button" value="Donate" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return IsTermChecked();">

 You have to use jquery library to user jQuery's functions. Try this. This will work definitely.
```

Comment: Dude i actually love you. That worked perfectly with my script! Big thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the submit button then enable it when the checkbox is checked:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
<!-- Add ranks with a new value on the next line! -->
<select name="rank">
<option value="1">Donator ($1.20)</option>
<option value="2">Moderator ($5.00)</option>
<option value="3">Administrator ($13.37)</option>
<option value="4">Super-Administrator ($33.00)</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="required">I agree to the <a href="/donate/tos/">terms of service</a>.<br />
<input type="submit" disabled role="button" type="submit" value="Donate" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("input[name='required']").click(function(){
   $("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q2kft/2/

To display the alert use the following:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
    if($("input[name='required']:checked").length == 0){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("You must check the input");
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q2kft/1/

Comment: That won't display an alert.

Comment: @Barmar I am proposing an alternate solution.

Comment: Yeah, thats perfect except for the Javascript Alert part :D But also once you check the checkbox and uncheck it right afterwards the button is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        if (!$(this).find(":checkbox[name=required]").is(":checked")) {
            alert ("You must agree to the terms of service.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. i put this into my <head> section just like this and its not working :/ the process just continues.. This is the page for testing although you'll need a steam account to go through the process and get to the page this validation is used on :( (you prob dont have one) http://blusttt.tk/donate/

Comment: this is how i added it `<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(function() {
    if (!$(this).find(":checkbox[name=required]").is(":checked")) {
        alert ("You must agree to the terms of service.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: Put all of the javascript within `$(document).ready(function(){/* your code here */});`, same goes for my code if your using the head section for the script.

Comment: I was missing a close parenthesis, and I've updated the answer to show that it should be in the document ready. I didn't realize I had to explain that, since it should be the first thing you learn when you learn jQuery (it's at the beginning of every tutorial I've seen).

Comment: Hmm okay so now i added

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        if (!$(this).find(":checkbox[name=required]").is(":checked")) {
            alert ("You must agree to the terms of service.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>`

to my <head> tag and its still not functional :/ the process is continued once you click the donate button